# iTunesArtwork breaking release submit to app store

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, xcode4

I have an iOS 4.3 iPhone app built in Xcode4 that I'm submitting through the Application Loader app.  I keep getting this error:

Icon specified in the Info.plist not found under the top level app wrapper: iTunesArtwork

I do have the following set:

- iTunesArtwork (JPEG with no extension) in root folder
- iTunesArtwork reference in Resources file
- 512x512 image size
- 'Item 0; under 'Icon Files' array in info.plist

Far as I can tell, the above is exactly as it should be for the iTunesArtwork.  Any ideas which step I missed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

iTunesArtwork should be a PNG file and you shouldn't include it in the Icon Files in info.plist.

Everything you need to know about app icons can be found in the following Q&A article.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html

Comment: But if i don't include the iTunesArtwork in my info.plist. then I won't get a Icon on my App Archives page? Why? Thanks

Comment: The link may outdated, as Apple is now requiring 1024x1024 icons; however, I can't seem to find whether this means the iTunesArtwork now needs to be 1024x1024 or if just the large app icon in iTunes Connect needs to be 1024x1024.

Comment: @JoshBrown I agree, the docs are confusing. This [blog post](http://blog.jaredsinclair.com/post/24248889488/the-ongoing-confusion-with-ios-app-icons) says to provide `iTunesArtwork` as 512 and `iTunesArtwork@2x` as 1024, however this is mentioned *nowhere* in the docs. Have you managed to clarify anything?

Comment: Not exactly, but I did submit an app update recently where I left the iTunesArtwork at 512 and just updated the large app icon in iTunes Connect to 1024. It seems like Apple will be content with this - if not, I'll post an update here.

Answer (score 5):

You just include the iTunesArtwork (png with no extension) in the root folder of your project.  Do not add it to your info.plist (this is unnessary and icons without extensions break Application Loader).  Your CFBundleIconFiles should contain these icons only:

- **Icon.png**
- **Icon-72.png** (optional for iPad)
- **Icon@2x.png** (optional for Retina)
- Icon-Small.png (optional for Search and Settings)
- Icon-Small-50.png (optional for search on an iPad)
- Icon-Small@2x.png (optional for Search and Settings)

*(You can replace the word Icon with whatever you want)*

The top three are the important ones, but since you already have the iTunesArtwork it isn't too hard to make the others.

You should also set your CFBundleIconFile to just Icon.png to support older iOS versions

Answer (score 1):

I think this blog will help you getting more details about current grapichs required for iOS app submission.

[The iTunesArtwork -
The Artwork need to do by every iOS Developer](http://knowledgetransferinobjectivec.blogspot.in/2012/05/itunesartwork-in-ios-apps.html)

thanks,

Naveen Shan