# icon Specified in the info.plist error

Tags: iphone

[image]

Hi ,
I am keep getting the same error again and again.
I hv icon.png in my resource folder,.
I tried delelting it and copying it again.
PLz guide me, how can i resolve this issue.

Comment: What is the dimensions of your icon file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627697/problem-with-icon-png-icon-specified-in-the-info-plist-not-found-under-the-top-l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls refer this previous SO question [iTunesArtwork breaking release submit to app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359804/itunesartwork-breaking-release-submit-to-app-store)